# Optimizing a sum function for computing

Tags: summation, computational-complexity, integers

For a game project with a leveling system, I have a function which calculates the amount of XP (experience points) to reach the next level, starting from the minimum amount required for the specified current level.

This function $f(c) = Δp$ is defined as following, **$c$ being the current level** and **$Δp$ being the XP required to reach the next level**:

$$f(c) = Δp = 5*(c^2)+(50*c)+100$$

---

My goal is to find a function $g(l) = p$ in which **$p$ is the total amount of required XP** to reach **the level $l$**.

I've came up with this sum solution, which adds the results of $f(c)$ together until $l$ is reached:

$$\sum_{c=0}^l f(c) = f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(l)$$

---

The problem with my solution is that the implementation of this in my program gets *very slow* with increasing $l$, as it has to call $f(c)$ exactly $l$ times. This is a problem for me, because it is possible in my environment that very large $l$ exist. I am pretty sure that I am already using the most optimal implementation for my sum solution.

So I am asking, is there any other way I can solve my problem, which may be faster for computing? Preferably a way which does not take more calculations the larger $l$ becomes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the first $m$ squares is 
$$
\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}.
$$
The sum of the first $m$ integers is
$$
\frac{m(m+1) }{2}.
$$
With these formulas you can find the sum of the first $m$ values of $f$ as a function of $m$ without ever evaluating $f$.

Make sure you get the start end conditions right, beginning at $0$ and ending where you wish.

Then I think you have a simple inequality to solve to find the value of $m$ for which the sum you care about first exceeds some known number.

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what I needed! My final solution is now $g(x) = (5 * s(x)) + (50 * i(x)) + (100 * (x + 1))$, $s(x)$ is the square function and $i(x)$ the integer function.